# Python iteration not capturing all data in WTForms data fields/fieldlist

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, wtforms

I've tried to simplify a previous question I asked earlier .
I have a FieldList Form:

```
class TrackForm(Form):
    name = TextField('name')
    start = StringField('Start Time')
    end = StringField('End Time')
class Merge(Form):
    item_description = FieldList(FormField(TrackForm), min_entries=2, max_entries=6)
```

I call the form in the test template and fill in the fields for multiple entries before submitting.

```
<form method="POST" >
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

{{ form.item_description }}

<input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:300px;"type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I'm using the below to iterate over the entries and to hopefully store all of them in the variable 'newdata'.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

        form=Merge()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
                for entry in form.item_description.entries:
                        newdata = entry.data
                        return redirect(url_for('test1', newdata=newdata))
        return render_template(
        'test.html', title='test', form=form)



@app.route('/test1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test1():
        newdata=request.args.get('newdata', '')
        return render_template(
        'test1.html', title='test1', newdata=newdata)
```

In the test1.html template I'm simply calling newdata like so:

```
{{ newdata }}
```

It only displays the data from the first inputted line of the form, not the others. Can you see why I am only managing to capture the first entry in the form?

Update:

When I try printing the data after validating the form, it seems the data in the form DOES contain all of the data input into the form:

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

```
    form=Merge1()
    #item_description = form.item_description.data or ''
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            print (form.item_description.data)
            for entry in form.item_description.entries:
                    newdata = entry.data
                    return redirect(url_for('test1', newdata=newdata))
    return render_template(
    'test.html', title='test', form=form)
```

^ this suggests the form entries are capable of storing data. However.....

When I try to print the entries after the form is validated, nothing gets printed:

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

```
    form=Merge1()
    #item_description = form.item_description.data or ''
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            print (form.item_description.entries)
            for entry in form.item_description.entries:
                    newdata = entry.data
                    return redirect(url_for('test1', newdata=newdata))
    return render_template(
    'test.html', title='test', form=form)
```

How can I use this to create a dictionary with all of the data in?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the `TrackForm`  class fields as well in your template. That means calling `description()`  instead of `description`

```
<form method="POST" >
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.item_description() }}
  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:300px;"type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And instead of doing this:

```
for entry in form.item_description.entries:
                        newdata = entry.data
```

You can use a `dict` instead:

```
form=Merge()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            newdata = {}
            for entry in form.item_description.entries:
                    newdata[entry] = entry.data
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. That does not seem to have worked. There wasn't an issue with rendering the fields- they are already visible. the issue revolves around the data once submit is pressed- it only seems to submit the data input in the first entry (i.. the first instance of name, start and end), not the data that I have input into the subsequent entries.

Comment: Try this instead: `for entry in form.item_description().entries` and  try to print and see what it gives you. I mean in your `/test` route.

Comment: Hello, i'm getting error  AttributeError: 'HTMLString' object has no attribute 'entries' when I add those parenthesis.

Comment: I see, but do you have this as well ` {{ form.item_description() }}`. just to be sure.

Comment: Yes I have that in the template also. Do you think the 'newdata = entry.data' is right for storing all entries or would it just store one?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the culprit. You are overwriting what you have there I think

Comment: You can make `newdata` a dictionary instead. `new_data[entry] =entry.data` for example

Comment: That hasn't worked, but I'm going to update the question, I've found some interesting clues but not sure what they mean.

Comment: Glad it helped:)